# How do I prevent ipv6 addresses being used in a mixed ipv4 ipv6 environment?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, raspberry-pi, ipv6

I have a raspberry pi in a closed network at a remote site. The closed network has a Teltonika RUT-951 router that connects back to base over a VPN across the remote site's LAN and Internet; with a fallback to a 4G connection across O2.

Until recently, all traffic came over the remote site's LAN and everything was hunky-dory. Last week, the remote site's internet went off and the RUT failed over to the 4G connection. Again all was OK; until the remote site's LAN came back and RUT failed-back to the LAN.

Now, connections fail from the Pi.

On investigation, all connections from the Pi are targeted at ipv6 addresses; whereas our local ISP (virginmedia) does not support ipv6.

What appears to have happened is that during the failover, the RUT and Pi were getting ipv6 addresses from O2, which they continue to use despite being rebooted. I can't prevent the Pi using ipv6 addresses and can find no way to disable ipv6 support on the Pi (it uses NetworkManager which is a complication).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Pi is still using an IPv6 address *after being rebooted*, that means one of two things:

1. Someone configured that address (and gateway) statically. Take a look at the NetworkManager connection profile using `nmcli con show <name>`. If "ipv6.method" is set to "manual", change it back to "auto".
2. There is still a router on its immediate network that continues advertising an IPv6 prefix. Install "ndisc6" and run `rdisc6 eth0` (perhaps with `--multiple`) to look for Router Advertisements – particularly the ones with 1) non-zero "Router Lifetime" and 2) at least one "Prefix" section. The former allows the Pi to pick up that router as a default gateway, the latter tells it how to autoconfigure an address.

   Note the MAC address of the device issuing the RA and remove it from the network (or try rebooting it). If it turns out to be the RUT, make sure it's not actually still connected to O2 – it should've stopped advertising the prefix *and* should've withdrawn it (i.e. advertised with lifetime of 0) as soon as the connection was lost.

As a temporary workaround, use `ip addr` and `ip route` to delete the global IPv6 address and the default gateway (the ::/0 route). If they keep coming back, see #2.

You *can* easily disable IPv6 via `nmcli con modify`, but that's only sweeping the problem under the rug: you still have IPv6 access being advertised to the rest of the network, even if you're pretending it's not there.

Comment: Thanks, mate. I'll do some digging.
The Pi doesn't have a static address configured, either for ipv4 or v6.